# Printing all texts, required only one

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, for-loop, element

I have a html file:

```
<div class="panel-heading">
Some Text1
<strong>Hello</strong>
</div>
<div>
Some Text2
Some Text3
<strong>
Hi1
Hi2
</strong
```

I want to print only **Hello** in my python script using selenium, so I tried:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='panel-heading']")    
for element in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('strong'):
    print (element.text)
```

The result is:

Hello

Hi1

Hi2

But I want only:

> **Hello**

Comment: Try using print(next(driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('strong')).text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='panel-heading']")
print(element.find_element_by_tag_name('strong').text)
```

to print *first* `strong` text from required `div`

Note that `for element in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('strong')` means to iterate over *all* `strong` nodes on page. You need to replace `driver` with `element` to iterate over descendant `strong`s of defined WebElement:

```
for strong in element.find_elements_by_tag_name('strong'):
    print(strong.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code give you list. So simply use first element of the list, which give you "Hello".

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('strong')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

```
for element in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('strong'):
    print(next(element.text for element in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('strong')))
```

Or less cryptic and more robust if there is no such element, just [`break`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) the loop after the print:

```
for element in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('strong'):
    print(element.text)
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

You did small mistake in your code, you get `div` with `panel-heading` but in the loop you iterate throw all elements with tag `strong` in DOM. Perhaps, here how you wanted it to be:

```
divElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='panel-heading']")    
for element in divElement.find_elements_by_tag_name('strong'):
    print (element.text)
```

But `div` with `panel-heading` contains only one `span` and `strong`, you can get it with css selector:

```
strongText = driver.find_element_css_selector(".panel-heading strong").text
```